# How to initialize transient fields during deserialization?

Tags: scala, serialization, jackson, deserialization, transient

Following code shows serialization and deserialization of simple classes using Jackson. Trouble is during deserialization normal constructor of `Root` is not called, and therefore the transient fields `name` of `Leaf` classes do not have values they had when constructed originally. Is there some way how to provide the transient fields with desired values, without having to make them vars? Some custom serializer or some clever annotations?

I do not want to serialize `name` values to keep the serialized format as compact as possible - after all the value is given by the data structure and it should be possible to recreate it from the structure again.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

class Leaf(val value:Int, @transient val name:String) {

  def this(@JsonProperty value:Int) = this(value,"")
}

class Root(val a: Leaf, val b:Leaf)

object Main extends App {
  val om = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper {
    registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)
  }

  val root = new Root(new Leaf(1,"a"), new Leaf(2, "b"))

  val out = om.writeValueAsString(root)

  println(out)

  val test = om.readValue(out, classOf[Root])

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Handling subobjects as part of the owning object

Even if `Leaf` objects are separate JVM objects, from serialization point of view they can be handled as  part of the `Root` object and all the naming can be done by its constructor. For this constructor params need to be annotated and getters created and annotated accessing inner `Leaf` values, while the `Leaf` values itself are marked `@transient`:

```
class Leaf(val value:Int, val name:String)

class Root(
  @(JsonProperty @param)("a") aVal: Int,
  @(JsonProperty @param)("b") bVal:Int
) {
  @transient val a = new Leaf(aVal,"a")
  @transient val b = new Leaf(bVal,"b")

  @(JsonProperty @getter) def getA = a.value
  @(JsonProperty @getter) def getB = b.value

}
```

#### Using @JsonDeserialier(as)

Another option is to use [@JsonDeserialier(as=xxx)](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html#as()) annotation, then you need to create subclasses for each transient value needed:

```
class LeafA(value:Int) extends Leaf(value,"a")
class LeafB(value:Int) extends Leaf(value,"b")

case class Root(
  @JsonDeserialize(as=classOf[LeafA]) a: Leaf,
  @JsonDeserialize(as=classOf[LeafB]) b: Leaf
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a method to name the `Leaf` instances in the alternate constructor.  This method could even retain state if necessary.  For example, the following will alternate calling each leaf `a` or `b`:

```
class Leaf(val value: Int, @transient val name: String) {
    def this(@JsonProperty value:Int) = { 
        this(value, Leaf.namer.next)
    }
}

object Leaf {
    private val namer = Iterator.continually(Seq("a", "b")).flatten
}
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, and would work in the simplified case of linear leaf naming. However the the real structure of leaves is more complex, one would get closer to it by making both a and b Option[Leaf]. It is then almost impossible to keep the namer consistent with the names given by the root - some coordination with root is most likely needed.

Comment: Another drawback: this does not seem the be thread safe. If multiple Roots are deserialized at the same time, the naming will go wrong.

Comment: All I meant to show was that you could use a method to name the leaves.  The method doesn't have to be this `namer`!  And I wanted to show that you could feasibly tie the method naming method to some state if desired.

Comment: I appreciate that, and it answers the question as written, but I am afraid unless the naming method is getting some context from the Root object being serialized, the thread safety or complex naming cannot be done. Or do you see some way how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I would have one question: what needs to know the leaf name?

1) From you example alone, no one. Or maybe Root, but it already knows which leaf is a or b, because it is the name of the variable. In this case, just remove the name from Leaf, and what ever method needs to get a name should get it from the Root object. Eg:

```
case class Leaf(value: Int)

class Root(val a: Leaf, val b: Leaf){
  def getLeavesWithName(): ((Leaf, String), (Leaf, String)) =
    ((a, "a"), (b,"b"))
```

This can be generalized, for example to a seq of leaves, by implementing the suitable naming rules in Root.

2) For some reason, Leaf can be of one of two types, which is related to its containing Root but can be treated independently from it.

In this case, use simple trait/(case)class hierarchy:

```
trait Leaf{ 
  val value: Int
  def name: String 
}
case class LeafA(value: Int){ def name = "a" }
case class LeafB(value: Int){ def name = "b" }

case class Root(a: LeafA, b: LeafB)
```

3) Leaf needs to have a name independent of Root, but there is no specific rules about naming: You simply use "a" and "b" in some cases, but that could be anything.

In this case, simply keep name in the Leaf serialization (no @transient)

---

Now, which ever choice you make about the above, if your question is about optimizing the serialization of Root without leaves name, or type, because Root implies it, then simply don't serialize Leaf object within Root serialization.

I'm not familiar with the serialization API you're using, so I cannot tell how to do it. But what you need is
 - a `Serializer[Root](w: Root) = Serializer[(Int, Int)].write(w.a, w.b)` that stores the values of a and b, and
 - a `Deserializer[Root](obj) = Deserializer[(Int, Int)].map((a,b) => new Root(a,b))` that takes those an make a Root instance.

You get what I mean